# Java-Documentbuilder Get single element tagcontent XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
<value type="typeabc" val="">
                <conditions>
                    <a>text 1</a>
                    <b>text 2</b>
                    <c>text 3</c>
                </conditions>
</value>
```

I am working with the documentbuilder/java for the first time and need to grab the content of Tag a (**text 1**).

Also the variable I am trying to save the content in expects an integer.

My idea was:

```
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("value"); 

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) { 
    Element el = (Element) nList.item(i); 
    int contenta = Integer.parseInt(el.getElementsByTagName("a")
        .item(i).getTextContent()); 
    if (value.conditions.a.isNotNull) { 
        value.conditions.a.value = contenta; 
    } 
}
```

Don't get confused by slightly odd syntax. I am working with mps jetbrains which complicates it a little bit but shouldnt change anything according to my question.

Do I even need to iterate through? Can I grab directly the content of a specific tag if it only apears once in the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I grab directly the content of a specific tag if it only apears once in the xml?

Of course you can. You can either navigate in Java from one node of the dom to the next, or you can use [XPath](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). The expression for your example would be `"/values/conditions/a"` or even simpler: `"//a"`.

Because using XPath requires some prearrangement (especially when using namespaces), I suggest the use of a [library](https://xmlbeam.org).
This could reduce the problem to a one liner:

```
String content = new XBProjector().io().file("xmlfile.xml").evalXPath("//a").as(String.class);
// content would contain "text 1"
```

If you want to read int values, it would look like this:

```
int content = new XBProjector().io().file("xmlfile.xml").evalXPath("//a").as(Integer.class);
```